$\mu^*(E \cap (A_1 \cup A_2)) = \mu^*(E \cap A_1) + \mu^*( E \cap A_2).$
Suppose that $\mu^*$ is an outer measure on $X, A_1, A_2$ are two disjoint $\mu^*$-measurable sets. Prove that for any $E \subset X,$ $$\mu^*(E \cap (A_1 \cup A_2)) = \mu^*(E \cap A_1) + \mu^*( E \cap A_2).$$
Some thoughts:
This direction $\leq$ is trivial by countable subadditivity. I also, know that $\mu^*(E \cap A_1 \leq \mu^*(E \cap (A_1 \cup A_2)$ and $\mu^*(E \cap A_2 \leq \mu^*(E \cap (A_1 \cup A_2)$ but then I do not know how to complete.

What does $\mu^*$-measurable mean? Doesn't the outer measure always exist, by definition? Did you mean $\mu$-measurable?

@ThomasAndrews I think the OP begins with a general outer measure, so the definition of $\mu^*$-measurable set is the usual one.

@ThomasAndrews see here.

Same problem

Define $\nu(\cdot) = \mu^*( E \cap\cdot)$, then any $\mu^*$-measurable set is also $\nu$-measurable. Indeed, let $A$ be $\mu^*$-measurable, and $B\subset X$ then
\begin{align}
\nu(B) =\mu^*(B\cap E) &=\mu(B\cap E \cap A)+ \mu((B\cap E)\setminus A) \\
&= \mu( (B\cap A )\cap E)+ \mu((B\setminus A)\cap E)\\
&=\nu(B\cap A) + \nu(B\setminus A).
\end{align}
It remains to prove that $A_1,A_2$ are disjoint $\nu$-measurable, then
$$ \nu(A_1 \cup A_2) = \nu(A_1)+\nu(A_2). $$
I leave the rest for you.
